# Firebase Cloud Messaging Error: Service messaging is not available

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have firebase installed (previously working with Auth, Firestore, Storage, with no problems) but when I want to implement messaging I have this error message:

[Error: Service messaging is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eno1H.png)

Working with Next.js.

This is my firebase.js config file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "--------------------",
  authDomain: "------------------",
  projectId: "--------------------",
  storageBucket: "--------------------",
  messagingSenderId: "------------------------",
  appId: "---------------------------",
  measurementId: "--------------------",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth();

export const db = getFirestore(app);

export const messaging = getMessaging(app);
```

I have already reinstalled firebase with version 9.15.0